# How to send ipn variables server-side?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a payment button that uses the custom variable to identify in my database who bought what when the ipn message comes. my custom field looks like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="userName">
```

My problem is that anybody can change this value to what ever they want, allowing people to buy stuff for other users. Is there any possible way to send this custom value from php to paypal, so that the user cannot change the value to something else?

Comment: you would use IPN to verify what was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of standard payment buttons.

You'd make a call to [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) to start the process and obtain a token, then redirect the user to PayPal.

When they're returned from PayPal you can call [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain the buyer information as returned by PayPal, and then you call [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) to finalize the order and actually move the money.

You would include the CUSTOM parameter in that final DECP request the same way you are now, but it would all be hidden in the PHP code, of course.  Nothing people would see in HTML.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make those API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: In case of Express Checkout the CUSTOM parameter is not really needed, nor the IPN. You can just update the database just after receiving a successful result for the DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Comment: IPN is still recommended to correctly handle pending payments that may not clear for a few days.  If you deliver a product prior to a pending payment clearing you could get end up getting burned.  It's also useful for automating tasks based on refunds, disputes, reversals, etc.

Comment: Agree, IPN is still recommended to correctly handle pending payments.